# OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: './C:\\Python\\\x07rchivo.txt'

Tags: python

Me encuentro realizando un pequeño programa en `Python` y me arroja este error en la segunda línea de código

> OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: './C:\Python\\x07rchivo.txt'

```
def funcion():
    ruta = open('./%s' % 'C:\Python\\\archivo.txt', 'r')
    archivo_leido = ruta.read()
    print (archivo_leido)
    ruta.close()

funcion()
```

Comment: Bienvenido, te recomiendo que sigas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) para entender lo básico sobre cómo preguntar en este sitio. Por ejemplo, deberías adjuntar un ejemplo mínimo y verificable del error, como así toda información adicional que ayude al diagnóstico del problema.

Comment: Solo tienes que quitar `./` de esa línea.

Answer (score 0):

Procura usar el **keyword with** para evitar cerrar el archivo manualmente y se libere de manera automatica.

```
def funcion():
    with open("C:\\Python\\archivo.txt","r") as f:
        archivo_leido = f.read()
        print(archivo_leido)


funcion()
```

Ademas si te es necesario formatear tu cadena con distintos parametros te aconsejo usar la funcion **format** sobre el **%**

```
def funcion():
    with open("{0}".format("C:\\Python\\archivo.txt"),"r") as f:
        archivo_leido = f.read()
        print(archivo_leido)


funcion()
```